# i was create two log files using RollingFileAppender in log4j.xml

Tags: java, log4j

I want to create two log file. 
Because my project has two modules and log each module in separate log files.
After that ,I have to log each module logging data independently .i have Single Log4j file.when i use appender -ref inside the root then i can achive but at that time aop or java logging cant appear in that file only manualy logger msg shown there

Comment: can you post your log4j.xml config

Comment: i am not able to share code due to company policy

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like :

```
<log4j:configuration>


    <appender name="fileAppender1" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">

        <param name="Threshold" value="ALL" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="3KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="File" value="F:/logs/Testing/Project_moduleOne.log" />

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-5p %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender2" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">

        <param name="Threshold" value="ALL" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="3KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="File" value="F:/logs/PAD_Testing/Project_moduleTwo.log" />


        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MMM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-5p %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <!--sets the priority log level for org.springframework -->
    <logger name="com.sp.logger1" additivity="false">
         <appender ref="fileAppender1"/>
    </logger>


    <logger name="com.sp.logger2" additivity="false">
        <appender ref="fileAppender2" />
    </logger>


    <!--sets the default priority log level -->
    <root>
        <priority value="all"></priority>
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender1" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender2" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: i did the same thing but not able to achive what i want bcoz when i add addititvity= "FALSE" it will log only which is manualy logged it was not logged AOP log